# Is there a way to get the first and third monday of a month in APEX

Tags: apex, date

I am trying to create a event on the first and third monday of the month. Is there a way i can do this?

if the first and third monday are greater than today then create them for the next month. if the first monday is less than today then create for third monday and 1 monday of next month.

Any pointer would be of great help

Answer (score 6):

```
    Date firstMonday = Date.today().toStartOfMonth().toStartOfWeek().addDays(1);    
    //add a week if "firstMonday" is in last month    
    if(firstMonday < date.today().toStartOfmonth()) firstMonday = firstMonday.addDays(7);
    Date thirdMonday = firstMonday.addDays(14);
```

Comment: Almost. This won't work if used in January, because 12 > 1. Instead, consider `if(firstMonday < date.today().toStartOfmonth())`... which should be correct for all usual cases.

Comment: nice catch sfdcfox, I edited the answer as you suggested